# Why does jQueryUI datepicker swap day and month on page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an MVC3 application where one of the pages has a [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#expirationDate").datepicker();
        $("#expirationDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
    });
</script>

using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("expirationDate")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

the controller action goes like this:

```
public ActionResult DoStuff(String expirationDate)
{
    return View();
}
```

The datepicker looks just fine but behaves strangely.

I enter some date into it like for example 31/12/2012 for Dec 31 (note I specified the format to be `dd/mm/yy`) and press the button. Control goes into the controller and there I see that `expirationDate` variable holds `31/12/2012` value. Then the action returns and then I see the textbox being empty.

Then I try 10/12/2012 - it gets into the action but when the page is displayed again it turns into 12/10/2012 - clearly the month and the day are swapped. Perhaps in case of 31/12 it saw that swapping them would yield an invalid date and just discarded that.

Why do day and month get swapped despite the format being explicitly specified?

Comment: What `datepicker` are you using? what's the homde site of that plugin? I'm sure that `"option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy"` is not valid! maybe `.datepicker({"dateFormat": "dd/mm/yy"})` will be a better option to try.

Comment: @balexandre: This one http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @balexandre For jqueryui datepicker option is correct behavior

Comment: @CoolEsh he didn't have specified when I have asked about :) and I never use jQuery UI, I prefer [Bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it. I changed

```
$("#expirationDate").datepicker();
$("#expirationDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

to

```
$("#expirationDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

and now it works just fine.

My guess is that the original code is just broken. I didn't craft the original code, I found it on [the datepicker page](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats).

Answer (score 1):

the javascript format `dd/mm/yy` is `01/12/2012`

in javascript `yy` has the same result as `yyyy` (this is because `getYear()` is deprecated in favor of `getFullYear()`

if you want only to get the last 2 digits of the year, you need to do the break yourself, either in javascript, like:

```
$(function() {

  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
      var dt = new Date(selectedDate),
          txt = (dt.getDate() + 100).toString().slice(1) + "/" + 
                (dt.getMonth() + 101).toString().slice(1) + "/" + 
                (dt.getFullYear()).toString().slice(2);

       $( "#datepicker" ).val(txt);
    }
  });

  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( 
    "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" 
  );

});
```

but you specify you're using ASP.NET, I would prefer to do it over in .NET

```
string dt = Request["expirationDate],
       expDate = DateTime.Parse(dt).ToString("dd/mm/yy");
```

Comment: My problem is not with retrieving the value, my problem is that when the page reloads the value is somehow changed.

Comment: but you're not giving the value upon reload ... you should have something like: `@Html.TextBox("expirationDate", Model.expirationDate)` or simply `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model.expirationDate)`

Comment: MVC3 has some magic for auto-mapping. And there is auto-mapping - when I initially have 10/12/2012 I get 12/10/2012 on reload, so it's not lost, it's just changed.

Comment: Well, it looks like I've got it resolved in a way I wouldn't expect - see my answer.